# Is it possible to do a If Else or a Switch Statement Firestore Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to do a Switch Statement or an if else in firestore rules?

I have tried to search for it with no luck of finding an answer.

What i tried was

```
function getTier() {
  return get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userTier;
}

function canAddProduct() {
  if getTier() == 'UserTier.FREE'
    // Do additional code 
    return doSomethingBasedOnFreeTier();
  else if getTier() == 'UserTier.SILVER'
    // Do additional code 
    return doSomethingBasedOnSilverTier()
  else if getTier() == 'UserTier.GOLD'
    // Do additional code 
    return doSomethingBasedOnGoldTier()
  else if getTier() == 'UserTier.COMPANY'
    // Do additional code 
    return doSomethingBasedOnCompanyTier()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if ... else` statements are not valid in the security rules for Firestore. But often you can accomplish the same result by another construct, like the `||` based approach that @denniskbijo showed in their answer. If that doesn't work for you, make sure to include the goal of the rule in your question, as right now it reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Feb 13, 2020 Firestore now supports the ternary operator

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020

Here's the documentation for the available operators (ternary is at the bottom)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions

Taking the example code from the question, the solution can be achieved by using a nested set of ternary operators

```js
function getTier() {
  return get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userTier;
}

function canAddProduct() {
  return getTier() == 'UserTier.FREE' ?
    doSomethingBasedOnFreeTier() :
    (
      getTier() == 'UserTier.SILVER' ?
        doSomethingBasedOnSilverTier() :
        (
          getTier() == 'UserTier.GOLD' ?
            doSomethingBasedOnGoldTier() :
            (
              getTier() == 'UserTier.COMPANY' ?
                doSomethingBasedOnCompanyTier() :
                null
            ) 
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 11):

One other hack to be aware of is the use of objects. It took me a while to figure out this was possible. You can put your different cases into an object and use the object keys as the switch.

```
function switchOnTier(tier) {
  return {
    'UserTier.FREE': doSomethingBasedOnFreeTier(),
    'UserTier.SILVER': doSomethingBasedOnSilverTier(),
    'UserTier.GOLD': doSomethingBasedOnGoldTier(),
    'UserTier.COMPANY': doSomethingBasedOnCompanyTier()
  }[tier]
}
```

Which you can then use like this..

```
return switchOnTier(getTier())
```

I'm using this for a simple case of trying to pluralize a string (which was surprisingly difficult to do)

```
function pluralize(str) {
  return {
    'AccessToken': 'AccessTokens',
    'Image': 'Images',
    'Index': 'Indexes'
  }[str]
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else struggling to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

Firestore Rules are meant to define the rules for accessing the particular collections in your Project.
They are primarily used to check access for the user. They are not meant for anything other than checking logic. So they don't support switch statements, if..else conditions and conditional expressions.

You can use OR condition to check if the user can add the product according to the UserTier he/she belongs to.

```
function canAddProduct() {
    return ( getTier() == 'UserTier.FREE' || getTier() == 'UserTier.SILVER' 
             || getTier() == 'UserTier.GOLD' || getTier() == 'UserTier.COMPANY' );
}
```

This is the simplest way of checking access.

However for your particular case try this. I'm assuming that you have further checks on the user according to the tier they belong to. 
Here I'm checking if the user's trial period is expired only if he is belonging to the FREE Tier.

```
function getUser() {
//Get the user
    return get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
}

function canAddProduct() {
    return ( getTier() == 'UserTier.FREE' && checkFreeTierAccess(getUser()) || 
             getTier() == 'UserTier.SILVER' && checkSilverTierAccess(getUser()) ||
             getTier() == 'UserTier.GOLD' && checkGoldTierAccess(getUser()) ||
             getTier() == 'UserTier.COMPANY' && checkCompanyTierAccess(getUser())
           );
 } 

function checkFreeTierAccess(user) {
//do the checks
    return user.isTrailPeriodExpired;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Not what i want to do. I dont want to always return true on getTier().  I want a case statement like condition to enable me to do more and different conditions based on getTier() value

Comment: Updated code to reflect more or less on what i want to do

Comment: @TinusJackson, the only valid output values are true and false, so everything you want to do can be boiled down to ANDs and ORs of different tests. For each UserTier, but it all in parentheses and OR them together like Dennis has shown above - it does the same thing.

Comment: or put another way, Security Rules don't allow you to 'doSomething()', they only allow you to 'checkSomething()', and the result of the check eventually needs to be true (allow) or false (don't allow).