# can I do something like if else statement in firestore security rules to set different action?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

in my document, there is 3 properties: price, capacity, title. I want only moderator that can update the capacity. I am using custom claim to differentiate a regular user or a moderator.

```
function isAModerator() {
    return request.auth.token.moderator == true
}
```

but I don't how to do something if else statement in firebase security rules, I want to do something like this

```
if (aModerator) {
   canUpdateCapacity()
} else {
   canNotUpdateCapacity()
}
```

I have read this [Possible to do a If Else or a Switch Statement Firestore Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336274/possible-to-do-a-if-else-or-a-switch-statement-firestore-rules) but it doesn't same with my case because it use Map, the key of map must be in string

Comment: The advice in the other question still applies.  You have to use logical AND and OR statements to return a single boolean for the permission.  There is no "do something" for security rules.  Every expression must evaluate down to a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit "if-else" syntax.

For your use case, the result you desire can be achieved by applying the restriction that capacity cannot be changed but also allowing that condition to fail if the user is a moderator:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAModerator() {
      return request.auth.token.moderator == true
    }

    // Make sure only moderators can change capacity
    match /items/{item} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.capacity == resource.data.capacity
                    || isAModerator()
    }
  }
}
```

Here `||` is an OR operation. You can also use `&&` for AND operations.

#### Working out

This result was achieved using boolean arithmetic.

```js
if (aModerator) {
  return true; // no restriction
} else {
  return enforceRestrictions(); // allow only if restrictions are satisfied
}
```

can be rewritten as

```js
(aModerator && true) || (!aModerator && enforceRestrictions())
```

which can be simplified to

```js
aModerator || (!aModerator && enforceRestrictions())
```

which can be expanded to

```js
(aModerator || !aModerator) && (aModerator || enforceRestrictions())
```

which can be simplifed to

```js
true && (aModerator || enforceRestrictions())
```

which becomes

```js
aModerator || enforceRestrictions()
```

Comment: The rules of simplification are summarised [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws). The notation used is `∨` for OR (`||`) and `∧` for AND (`&&`)

Comment: If you also wanted to restrict updates to logged in users, you would use `isLoggedIn() && (request.resource.data.capacity == resource.data.capacity || isAModerator())`